# Sending data to the homepage on the page with Javascript Popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function PostData() {

         var NameID = '<%= this.Request.QueryString["UN"] %>';

         window.showModalDialog('PopUp.aspx?UN=' + cosh +'',  'height=400,width=450');
         window.opener.document.getElementById(NameID).innerHTML = document.getElementById('<%= cosh.ClientID%>').value;
         return false;
     }
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    var cosh = '<%= gelen_cosh.ClientID %>';

</script>
```

I use this method to keep the data being sent.
**Watching a way to send the data as shown above but the *"cosh"* says undefined variable. Am I on the right way? Can you provide an example or document?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try swapping the position of the script blocks so

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    var cosh = '<%= gelen_cosh.ClientID %>';

</script>
```

comes first otherwise it will think isn't undefined

OR just put them in the same script block

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function PostData() {

         var cosh = '<%= gelen_cosh.ClientID %>';
         var NameID = '<%= this.Request.QueryString["UN"] %>';

         window.showModalDialog('PopUp.aspx?UN=' + cosh +'',  'height=400,width=450');
         window.opener.document.getElementById(NameID).innerHTML = document.getElementById('<%= cosh.ClientID%>').value;
         return false;
     }
 </script>
```

To be fair once you've done that they're could be something else wrong. See how it goes

Cheers

**EDIT**

Try this. You were getting a client id on the cosh variable which is itself just a client id as a string. You need to do document.getElementById straight away

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function PostData() {

         var NameID = '<%= this.Request.QueryString["UN"] %>';
         var cosh = document.getElementById('<%= gelen_cosh.ClientID%>');

         window.showModalDialog('PopUp.aspx?UN=' + cosh +'',  'height=400,width=450');
         window.opener.document.getElementById(NameID).innerHTML = cosh.value;
         return false;
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: Did't eat your way bro. The same problem continues